# Trouble reaching client website from my computer with traceroute

Tags: ip, wireless, ping, traceroute

I've been working on a client site for a few months now and I'm suddenly having a lot of trouble accessing it.

Chrome tells me:

This webpage is not available
Google Chrome's connection attempt to [client] was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

The website is available on any other computer, whether on the same wireless connection or not.

My traceroute shows a hop to localhost and then it stops. Interestingly enough, if I remove the "www" the site loads, and the traceroute without www works normally.

I've tried resetting my wireless adapter. I've tested this on multiple wireless networks and it just does not work on my computer.

I had this problem a few nights ago and it mysteriously worked for about a day and then the problem resumed this morning.

I do not have any proxy settings in Chrome. I've tried cycling the adapter, renewing the lease, and trying other routers. Just now, I also tried on ethernet and the problem persists. The problem also persists over users and browsers.

I don't notice any other sites affected.  I am currently using a Mac. If I use Parallels to use Windows, it has no problem connecting to the site or tracing properly.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to flush the routing table on your machine?

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/route flush
```

Comment: [OP]: No affect. Log attached.: ROGER-WILCO:~ User$ /usr/bin/sudo /sbin/route flush
Password:
default              192.168.1.1          done
route: write to routing socket: No such process
got only -1 for rlen

Comment: I also attempted to flush DNS while I was it, no changes.

Comment: How about route -n flush ? Afterwards disable/enable network adapter.

Comment: I fixed the problem. My hosts file was pointing the domain to localhost. I've never modified the hosts file on this computer, so I'm going to just forgive and forget. Since it specified www in the host file, it also explains why the domain worked without the www. Thank you Silviu for your support in troubleshooting this.

Comment: right! I should have thought about that, because I had problems with it too, especially when you change it for some games :) Great that it works now! Cheers!